# batch file to list all folders in a directory input as a variable, that don't contain sub folders

Tags: batch-file, cmd, directory, subdirectory

As the title says, I need to list all of the sub folders in a directory, that do not contain sub folders themselves. The best I've managed so far is listing all folders that DO contain sub folders. So I basically need it to do the opposite of what it does currently.

```
@echo off
for /d %%i in ("%1\*") do for /d %%j in ("%%~i\*") do (if exist %%~j echo %%~i)
```

Where `%1` is the directory variable in question.

Answer (score 0):

The task to output only the directories not containing any subdirectory in a directory of which path is passed to the batch file as first argument string can be done with a batch file with just the following single command line:

```
@if not "%~1" == "" for /D %%I in ("%~1\*") do @dir "%%I" /AD /B | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R "." >nul || echo %%I
```

`@` at beginning of the command line disables output of the entire command line after parsing it by `cmd.exe` before executing it.

The **IF** condition checks if the batch file was started with at least one non-empty argument string. There is done nothing if the batch file is started without any argument string like on double clicking on it in *Windows File Explorer* or on running it with just `""` as first argument string.

The `for /D` loop searches in the directory of which path was passed to the batch file for any subdirectory. Each found subdirectory is assigned with path to the specified loop variable `I` before executing the command line.

`@` left to command `dir` prevents the output of the command line executed several times by **FOR** depending on number of subdirectories found in the specified directory.

There is run for each subdirectory in specified directory the command **DIR** to output in bare format because of option `/B` just file system entries with the directory attribute because of option `/AD`, i.e. a list of subdirectories in the directory of which path is assigned currently to the loop variable `I`.

A directory has always two subdirectories: `.` and `..`
**DIR** exits for that reason always with exit code 0 for success even if there are no real subdirectories. This is the reason for redirecting with `|` the output of **DIR** to input of **FINDSTR** which searches on all lines output by **DIR** with a regular expression for any character.

The output of **FINDSTR** on finding any line with a least one character is of no interest and is redirected for that reason to device **NUL** to suppress it. There is only of interest the exit code of **FINDSTR** which is either `0` on **DIR** output any directory name or `1` on **DIR** output nothing and so **FINDSTR** could not find any character.

There is executed the command **ECHO** to output the directory path assigned currently to the loop variable `I` if **DIR** could not find any subdirectory in this directory with the exception of `.` and `..` not output because of using bare output format. Please see [single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) for an explanation of conditional command operator `||`.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `call /?` ... explains `%~1` ... first argument string with surrounding `"` removed
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`